# Jquery Get Input by Id within TD that is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi im trying to get an input that is contained in a TD using the `find()` function.

But i'm getting an error.

**This is my code:**

```
var  ItxExtend={
CurrentSelectedIds : "",
IsSelected:false,
HiddenFieldId:"",
CurrentSelectedIds:"",
CheckBoxClass:"",
HiddenFieldRowId :"",
DivToInitId :"",
SeleccionarCheckbox :function (TrFromTableInPages){
    var $tds = $(TrFromTableInPages).find("td");   
    var $ik = $tds[0];

    var $c = $ik.find(this.CheckBoxClass); 
    var $item =$ik.find(this.HiddenFieldRowId).val();
```

}

> Error: 
>   customJS.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: $ik.find is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $ik = $tds[0];
```

Here, you're selecting the element itself, not the jquery-wrapped element. Instead, try

```
$($tds[0]).find( ...
```

Comment: @user3893460 When an answer solves your problem, please Accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry, but that option was blocked.

Answer (score 1):

`$tds[0];` returns a raw dom element, not a jQuery object, so you cannot do jQuery methods off of it.  Change it to `$tds.eq(0);` and you will be able to use the find off of it.

Comment: Thanks! For your answer!